# c# inline function arguments and temporary variables

Tags: c#, argument-passing

I was wondering about the following situation in C#.

Sometimes function names can be quite long, and verbose. I'm using Microsoft's MVC 3 framework for a website at work, Here's an example function:

```
[ImportModelStateFromTempData]
[BreadCrumb("New Event")]
public ActionResult New()
{
    var @event = _dbContext.EventRepository.CreateNewEvent();

    return View("New", 
        EventViewModel.FromEventDomainModel(@event));
}
```

This code could be rewritten without use of the temporary variables @event, like so:

```
[ImportModelStateFromTempData]
[BreadCrumb("New Event")]
public ActionResult New()
{
    return View("New", 
        EventViewModel.FromEventDomainModel(_dbContext.EventRepository.CreateNewEvent()));
}
```

The first example is obviously more clear, but from a pure curiosity perspective/performance perspective, is either faster than the other? Especially considering that the cached value @event is only being used once.

In C++ I remember finding out that the local variable declaration of @event (if this were C++) would be stored in New()'s stack frame, and the assembly generated would be SLIGHTLY slower than directly in-lining the argument (as opposed to storing it in a temporary).

Is the C# compiler smarter about this situation? Am I free to use temporary's without the same performance considerations?

I understand that pre-optimization is evil, and I absolutely should not be worried about this kind of this, but I am curious about this. I'm not even sure about where I would go looking up more information about this, as the title was the best way I could describe my question. So what do you think Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IL produced by these will be equivalent.  If you want to prove it to yourself, try compiling both and looking at the resulting IL with Ildasm http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Temporary variables are good.

When you are debugging, you can check the results of functions.

The delay, if there is one, is in nano or pico seconds.

Maintenance is king.